# Get the id of a declared QMetaType at compile time?

Tags: c++, qt, variant, compile-time, compile-time-constant

I'm trying to register `std::string` for use with QVariant, and have it convert to another type which also functions as a variant, but is needed for serialization. I tried to do this with the following code:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (std::string)


const int std_string_enum = qMetaTypeId<std::string>();


void to_example_type(example_type &j, const QVariant &q_variant) {
qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");
    switch (q_variant.userType()) {
        case QMetaType::Bool:
            j = q_variant.value<bool>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::Int:
            j = q_variant.value<int>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::UInt:
            j = q_variant.value<unsigned int>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::Double:
            j = q_variant.value<double>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::Long:
            j = q_variant.value<long>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::LongLong:
            j = q_variant.value<long long>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::Short:
            j = q_variant.value<short>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::Char:
            j = q_variant.value<char>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::ULong:
            j = q_variant.value<unsigned long>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::ULongLong:
            j = q_variant.value<unsigned long long>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::UShort:
            j = q_variant.value<unsigned short>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::UChar:
            j = q_variant.value<unsigned char>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::Float:
            j = q_variant.value<unsigned char>();
            break;
        case QMetaType::QString:
            j = (q_variant.value<QString>()).toStdString();
        case std_string_enum:
            j = q_variant.value<std::string>();
            break;
        default:
            assert((false, "Can't Convert to example_type"));
            break;
    }
}
```

but was met with the following error:

```
error: the value of 'std_string_enum' is not usable in a constant expression

     case std_string_enum:

note: 'std_string_enum' was not initialized with a constant expression
 const int std_string_enum = qMetaTypeId<std::string>();

note: 'static constexpr int QMetaTypeId2<T>::qt_metatype_id() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]' is not usable as a constexpr function because:
     static inline Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR int qt_metatype_id() { return QMetaTypeId<T>::qt_metatype_id(); }
```

If I declare it instead constant expression:

```
constexpr int std_string_enum = qMetaTypeId<std::string>();
```

I get the following error:

```
in constexpr expansion of 'qMetaTypeId<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >()'

error: 'static constexpr int QMetaTypeId2<T>::qt_metatype_id() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]' called in a constant expression
     return QMetaTypeId2<T>::qt_metatype_id();

note: 'static constexpr int QMetaTypeId2<T>::qt_metatype_id() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]' is not usable as a constexpr function because:
     static inline Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR int qt_metatype_id() { return QMetaTypeId<T>::qt_metatype_id(); }

error: call to non-constexpr function 'static int QMetaTypeId<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::qt_metatype_id()'
 static inline Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR int qt_metatype_id() { return QMetaTypeId<T>::qt_metatype_id(); }
```

I'm confused by this error, as [the documentation states](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qMetaTypeId) (emphasis mine):

> **Returns the meta type id of type T at compile time.** If the type was
>   not declared with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(), compilation will fail.

After googling this, I found [this correspondence](http://development.qt-project.narkive.com/BVoY97h9/constexpr-and-qmetatypeid), which was only available through a third party archival site as google hadn't cached the results:

> > Post by a***@fastmail.fm Thiago - The qMetaTypeId documentation
> >     (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmetatype.html#qMetaTypeId)
> >     specifically states that the type registration using this function is
> >     resolved at compile-time, not run-time.
>
> The documentation is wrong. What Stephen said is correct.

however this was made 5 years ago, and I'm skeptical that the documentation wouldn't have been corrected or been proven correct in that time!

This seems like a fairly common problem in order to use qvariants with other systems, what if anything can I do to properly use QVariant in this scenario? Is there some way I can get the ID at compile time?

Note I'm using C++ 14 with Qt 5.8, if I need to upgrade qt however I can.

EDIT:

I've upgraded my mingw-64 version and my QT version, it still gives the same error.  Additionally I've tried just registering a blank struct like so:

```
struct Test{
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (Test)


const int test_enum= qMetaTypeId<Test>();
```

and it doesn't work

Comment: The error message says that `const int` is not usable in a constant expression. Use `constexpr`.

Comment: @Jaa-c That also doesn't work, see my edit

Comment: This most likely means that `Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR` is not `constexpr` in your setup.

Comment: @Jaa-c clion's code analyzer seems to think that the macro is going to be defined... so something really screwey must be going on if that is the case, it would only be blank and not constexpr if my compiler wasn't c++11+, and I have `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` in my cmake file, and I make clear use of other features from C++14 and it compiles fine with just those.

Comment: Which compiler exactly do you use? Check `QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h`, there are various conditions for macro `Q_COMPILER_CONSTEXPR` to be defined.

Comment: @Jaa-c I'm using `Mingw64 version x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0`,  and following the declaration of the macro shows it being defined in `qcompilerdetection.h` for me, and when I said that the code analyzer seems to think the macro is going to be defined, I meant that it shows it being defined ***as constexpr***, not just declared. The other code paths for macro definition are greyed out, it thinks that `#if defined Q_COMPILER_CONSTEXPR
# if defined(__cpp_constexpr) && __cpp_constexpr-0 >= 201304` are both true, which leads to every constexpr macro being defined as `constexpr`